# distinguish us.archive.ubuntu.com downtime from DNS issue

Tags: dns, network-monitoring, uptime

Between approximately this time:

```
Fri Jul  3 19:31:00 UTC 2020
```

and approximately this time:

```
Fri Jul  3 20:31:00 UTC 2020
```

I couldn't install any packages from `us.archive.ubuntu.com`,
but otherwise my connection was fine.

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall k4dirstat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 230 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 k4dirstat amd64 3.1.3-1
  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/k4dirstat/k4dirstat_3.1.3-1_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

That's over an hour of downtime,
but there wasn't anything on the Canonical status page.

> Jul 3, 2020
>
> No incidents reported today

https://status.canonical.com/

I can't replicate the problem anymore,
but here is the output of several commands during the interruption:

```
$ ping -c 5 us.archive.ubuntu.com
connect: Network is unreachable
$ host -v us.archive.ubuntu.com
Trying "us.archive.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6730
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;us.archive.ubuntu.com.     IN  A

Received 39 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53 in 0 ms
Trying "us.archive.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7987
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;us.archive.ubuntu.com.     IN  AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  60  IN  AAAA    2001:67c:1562::15
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  60  IN  AAAA    2001:67c:1562::18

Received 95 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53 in 25 ms
Trying "us.archive.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31711
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;us.archive.ubuntu.com.     IN  MX

Received 39 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53 in 23 ms
$ dig us.archive.ubuntu.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> us.archive.ubuntu.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18603
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;us.archive.ubuntu.com.     IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 03 16:10:01 EDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 50

$ systemd-resolve us.archive.ubuntu.com
us.archive.ubuntu.com: resolve call failed: 'us.archive.ubuntu.com' does not have any RR of the requested type
$ nslookup us.archive.ubuntu.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   us.archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 2001:67c:1562::15
Name:   us.archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 2001:67c:1562::18

$ wget --no-proxy --spider us.archive.ubuntu.com
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2020-07-03 16:11:52--  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/
Resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)... 2001:67c:1562::15, 2001:67c:1562::18
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|2001:67c:1562::15|:80... failed: Network is unreachable.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|2001:67c:1562::18|:80... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

and after the interruption:

```
$ ping -c 5 us.archive.ubuntu.com
PING ubuntu.com (91.189.88.180) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from cactuar.canonical.com (91.189.88.180): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=75.1 ms
64 bytes from cactuar.canonical.com (91.189.88.180): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=129 ms
64 bytes from cactuar.canonical.com (91.189.88.180): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=82.9 ms
64 bytes from cactuar.canonical.com (91.189.88.180): icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=76.4 ms
64 bytes from cactuar.canonical.com (91.189.88.180): icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=79.7 ms

--- ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 75.176/88.823/129.794/20.661 ms
$ host -v us.archive.ubuntu.com
Trying "us.archive.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20309
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;us.archive.ubuntu.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  3   IN  A   91.189.91.39
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  3   IN  A   91.189.91.38

Received 71 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53 in 2 ms
Trying "us.archive.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15398
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;us.archive.ubuntu.com.     IN  AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  4   IN  AAAA    2001:67c:1562::18
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  4   IN  AAAA    2001:67c:1562::15

Received 95 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53 in 1 ms
Trying "us.archive.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8865
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;us.archive.ubuntu.com.     IN  MX

Received 39 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53 in 86 ms
$ dig us.archive.ubuntu.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> us.archive.ubuntu.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 37941
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;us.archive.ubuntu.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  17  IN  A   91.189.91.39
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  17  IN  A   91.189.91.38

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 03 16:53:02 EDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 82

$ systemd-resolve us.archive.ubuntu.com
us.archive.ubuntu.com: 91.189.91.38
                       91.189.91.39

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 84.5ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
$ nslookup us.archive.ubuntu.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   us.archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.91.39
Name:   us.archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.91.38
Name:   us.archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 2001:67c:1562::18
Name:   us.archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 2001:67c:1562::15

$ wget --no-proxy --spider us.archive.ubuntu.com
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2020-07-03 16:52:41--  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/
Resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.91.39, 91.189.91.38, 2001:67c:1562::18, ...
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.39|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Remote file exists and could contain further links,
but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.
```

My questions:

- Was this due to Ubuntu server downtime, some kind of transient DNS problem from my ISP, or something else entirely?
- In case of future interruptions, how should I distinguish Ubuntu server downtime from a DNS problem?
- Is there a place I can go to check the status of a subdomain like `us.archive.ubuntu.com`?

Comment: Your output looks like classic DNS congestion or outage to me: During the outage, your ping didn't resolve to an IP address. Had you pinged the IP address (91.189.88.180) and received inadequate response, then *that* would be the server or ISP.

Comment: @user535733 Interesting. But why would it be just `us.archive.ubuntu.com` and not `ubuntu.com`? I could run `wget --spider ubuntu.com` without issue, and `ping` it as well. Or is that an expected behavior of DNS congestion?

Comment: DNSs are funny that way.